# Hide element with a condition

Tags: angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide

Alright, this is pretty straight forward: I need to hide one `<li>` when the percentage of work done is under 10%.
This is the element in my twig file and I want to hide that first li tab and make the second active when the first is hidden:

```
<nav ng-controller="OverviewController">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="active"></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>  
        <li ng-if="announcements.length > 0">    
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And there's a variable named "`percentage`" in my `ProjectManager.php` that will be the trigger to hide or show if under or above 10%.
Basically, want something like this: `if(percentage < 10%) { ng-hide }`

EDIT: 
OverviewController

```
define([], function() {
    OverviewController.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout', 'AnnouncementFactory', 'CommentFactory'];

    /**
     * Overview controller.
     */

    function OverviewController($scope, $timeout, AnnouncementFactory, CommentFactory) {
        $scope.announcementNotification = AnnouncementFactory.hasUnreadAnnouncements();
        $scope.announcements = AnnouncementFactory.getAnnouncements();
        $scope.commentNotification = CommentFactory.hasUnreadComments();

        // Cached this page date.
        var date = new Date().toISOString();

        /**
         * Set all announcements as read.
         */

        $scope.setAllAnnouncementsAsRead = function() {
            if (!$scope.announcementNotification) {
                return;
            }

            AnnouncementFactory.setAllAnnouncementsAsRead(date).then(function() {
                $scope.announcementNotification = false;
            });
        };

        /**
         * Set all comments as read.
         */

        $scope.setAllCommentsAsRead = function() {
            if (!$scope.commentNotification) {
                return;
            }

            CommentFactory.setAllCommentsAsRead().then(function() {
                $scope.commentNotification = false;
            });
        };
    }

    return OverviewController;
});
```

ProjectManager.php

```
/**
     * Update percentage.
     */
    public function updatePercentage($project)
    {
        $done = 0;
        $total = 0;

        list($pages, $status) = $this->participationManager->getPagesInPath($project);

        foreach ($pages as $pageData) {
            $widgetsDoneIds = array_keys($status[$pageData['module']]['pages'][$pageData['page']->getId()]['widgetsDone']);

            foreach ($pageData['widgets'] as $widget) {
                if (in_array($widget->getId(), $widgetsDoneIds)) {
                    $done++;
                }
            }

            $total += count($pageData['widgets']);
        }

        $percentage = $total !== 0 ? ($done / $total) * 100 : 0;

        $project->setPercentage($percentage);

        $this->entityManager->persist($project);
        $this->entityManager->flush($project);
    }
```

Comment: `ng-hide="percentage<10"`

Comment: @Weedoze Also tried that and didn't work

Comment: If you tried that why are you not showing it ? Add it in your question

Comment: @christopher-haugaard is there any variable called '$scope.percentage' in your OverviewController? Can you share your controller code?

Comment: add code for `ProjectManager.php` maybe `percentage` is a local variable there.

Comment: @HasanIbrahim No, there isn't

Comment: @christopher-haugaard please provide the controller code. Then we can help. Because the problem is in the controller. It's nothing with the view

Comment: @christopher-haugaard I don't see anything that passes the update of the percentage to the client side. You need to have a mechanism to pass the percentage completed in the your controller from the server in real time.

Comment: @HasanIbrahim Would you like to elaborate?

Comment: @christopher-haugaard what I mean is, the percentage is at the server side. You need to pull that information periodically in the client side in your controller.

Comment: You have an Angular application (client side) and a php server (server side). I'm sure the client and the server communicate somehow. What you need to do is have your client request the percentage form the server via a GET request or whatever request you are using.

So when the client gets the percentage information in the controller, it can expose this to the view